# Extract 10 CONTINUOUS digit from a string in r

Tags: r

Example I have strings like, 
str("98u90", "sanjay gupta 9822923774", "58lokesh 8574165987")

I want result as 
c(NA, 9822923774, 8574165987)

Means,I only want to extract continuous 10 digit from string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(str1, "\\d{10}"))
#[1]         NA 9822923774 8574165987
```

Comment: Thank you, you are amazing!

Comment: What if I want to extract all numbers greater than 10? 
Or if I want everything between 10-12 digits?

Comment: @LaksheySinghal  Then specify the range `\\d{10,12)`

Comment: Sure Thanks @akrun
I am sorry, I am bit new to r

Comment: @LaksheySinghal  No problem.  Glad to help you